# Pandas сортировка по общей сумме колонки

Tags: python, pandas

Помогите пожалуйста, есть датафрейм

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Code":["004","001","002","003","001","001","003","004","004","004","001"],
                   "Products":["Name4","Name1","Name2","Name3","Name1","Name1","Name3","Name4","Name4","Name4","Name1"],
                   "Qty":["1","1","2","2","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
                   "Person":["Mr_X","Mr_X","Mr_X","Mr_X","Mr_X","Mr_Y","Mr_Y","Mrs_Y","Mrs_Z","Mrs_Z","Mrs_Z"],
                   "Price":["10","50","100","75","50","50","75","10","10","10","10"]})



   Code Products Qty Person Price
0   004    Name4   1   Mr_X    10
1   001    Name1   1   Mr_X    50
2   002    Name2   2   Mr_X   100
3   003    Name3   2   Mr_X    75
4   001    Name1   1   Mr_X    50
5   001    Name1   1   Mr_Y    50
6   003    Name3   1   Mr_Y    75
7   004    Name4   1  Mrs_Y    10
8   004    Name4   1  Mrs_Z    10
9   004    Name4   1  Mrs_Z    10
10  001    Name1   1  Mrs_Z    10
```

я не понимаю как отсортировать Code по **общей** сумме QTY. Т.е. в данном примере Code 003 общее количество 3, 002 = 2, 001 = 4, 004 = 4 сортировка происходит от меньшего к большему.

ожидаемый результат:

```
   Code Products Qty Person Price
0   002    Name2   2   Mr_X   100
1   003    Name3   2   Mr_Y    75
2   003    Name3   1   Mr_X    75
3   001    Name1   1   Mr_X    50
4   001    Name1   1   Mr_X    50
5   001    Name1   1   Mr_Y    50
6   001    Name1   1   Mr_Y    50
7   004    Name4   1  Mrs_Y    10
8   004    Name4   1  Mrs_Z    10
9   004    Name4   1  Mrs_Z    10
10  004    Name4   1  Mrs_Z    10
```

пытался отсортировать методом sort

```
df.sort_values(by=['Code','QTY'], inplace=True)
```

как я понимаю нужно использовать groupBy, но не понимаю как сохранить значения в колонках Person и Price. Вопрос: как отсортировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это не ошибка, и в колонке Qty - строки, сначала приводим их к целому. Потом делаем индекс как сумму Qty в группировке по Code, далее сортируем по индексу и сбрасываем его.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Code": ["001", "001", "002", "003", "001", "001", "003"],
                   "Products": ["Name1", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name1", "Name1", "Name3"],
                   "Qty": ["1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1"],
                   "Person": ["Mr_X", "Mr_X", "Mr_X", "Mr_X", "Mr_X", "Mr_Y", "Mr_Y"],
                   "Price": ["50", "50", "100", "75", "50", "50", "75"]})
df.Qty = df.Qty.astype(int)
df.index = df.groupby("Code")['Qty'].transform(sum)
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

```
  Code Products  Qty Person Price
0  003    Name3    1   Mr_X    75
1  003    Name3    1   Mr_Y    75
2  002    Name2    3   Mr_X   100
3  001    Name1    1   Mr_X    50
4  001    Name1    1   Mr_X    50
5  001    Name1    1   Mr_X    50
6  001    Name1    1   Mr_Y    50
```

Вариант 2 - с многоуровневой сортировкой

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Code": ["004", "001", "002", "003", "001", "001", "003", "004", "004", "004", "001"],
                   "Products": ["Name4", "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name1", "Name1", "Name3", "Name4", "Name4",
                                "Name4", "Name1"],
                   "Qty": ["1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"],
                   "Person": ["Mr_X", "Mr_X", "Mr_X", "Mr_X", "Mr_X", "Mr_Y", "Mr_Y", "Mrs_Y", "Mrs_Z", "Mrs_Z",
                              "Mrs_Z"],
                   "Price": ["10", "50", "100", "75", "50", "50", "75", "10", "10", "10", "10"]})
print(df)
df.Qty = df.Qty.astype(int)
df['sort'] = df.groupby("Code")['Qty'].transform(sum)
df = df.groupby(['sort', 'Code']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Price', ascending=False)).drop(
    columns=['sort']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

```
   Code Products  Qty Person Price
0   002    Name2    2   Mr_X   100
1   003    Name3    2   Mr_X    75
2   003    Name3    1   Mr_Y    75
3   001    Name1    1   Mr_X    50
4   001    Name1    1   Mr_X    50
5   001    Name1    1   Mr_Y    50
6   001    Name1    1  Mrs_Z    10
7   004    Name4    1   Mr_X    10
8   004    Name4    1  Mrs_Y    10
9   004    Name4    1  Mrs_Z    10
10  004    Name4    1  Mrs_Z    10
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! но сортировка происходит не корректно, при появлении множества одинаковых сумм, я поправил пример.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, см. вариант 2